# linking within javascript event

Tags: javascript, events, hyperlink, calendar

I have a list of events for a calendar. I'd like to hyperlink the title or location--though preferably the location (see below) to a website. How do I do this?

```
var events = [
{ date: "2015-10-10", title: 'October 15, 2015', location: 'Event One Deadline' }, 
{ date: "2015-10-25", title: 'October 25, 2015', 'location: 'Payment Deadline' },
{ date: "2015-12-25", title: 'December 25, 2015', location: 'Christmas: We're closed.' },
{ date: "2015-12-26",    title: 'December 26, 2015', location: 'Boxing Day: We're closed.'}  ];
```

Comment: you need  to escape `'` by `\'`

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right you want to change the data of location to make it a link, so here you go:

```
events.map(function( row,index ){

     row.location = '<a href="#">' + row.location + '</a>';

});
```

or the old way

```
for( var i = 0, length = events.length; i < length; i++ ) {

     events[i].location = '<a href="#">' + events[i].location + '</a>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question, you need to parse JSON data.
Your code is JSON object
you can use `jSON.parse(JSON_DATA)`

```js
var events = [
{ date: "2015-10-10", title: "October 15, 2015", location: "Event One Deadline" }, 
{ date: "2015-10-25", title: "October 25, 2015", location: "Payment Deadline" },
{ date: "2015-12-25", title: "December 25, 2015", location: "Christmas: We're closed." },
{ date: "2015-12-26",    title: "December 26, 2015", location: "Boxing Day: We're closed."}  ];
 console.log(events); // Object
for(i=0;i<=events.length;i++){
  console.log(events[i].date);
  console.log(events[i].location);
  console.log(events[i].title);
  }
```

now values can use for make links
Note: your JSON data need to have double-qutos (**""**) instead of **''**

you can now access value like: `events[0].title` and create link like:
events[0].location